# Connect multiple unix servers from putty/plink

Tags: unix, ssh, cmd, putty, plink

Problem Statement:

```
Step1: Connect to unix server1 from windows cmd.exe

Step2: Connect to the unix server2 in the same putty/plink session.
```

Code used:

D:\Putty\putty.exe -ssh  -l xxx -pw xxx >D:\Putty\log44.txt

D:\Putty\putty.exe -ssh  -l xxx -pw xxx >D:\Putty\log45.txt

it is creating two putty sessions (two windows are getting displayed)

I want the command to launch server1 and server2, to be passed to the same putty session (window).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the GNU utility called screen.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

login on the first terminal and execute:

```
$ screen
```

then login on the second connection and execute:

```
$ screen -ls
```

then you'll see a list of session PIDs then execute:

```
$ screen -x PID
```

and you'll be connected to the same session.